# Append string to child link URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

What's the best way to append a string to the end of links in a list with Javascript?
From:

```
<div id="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://site.com/P1/">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://site.com/P2/">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://site.com/P1/?some=blah">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://site.com/P2/?some=blah">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ExpressionEngine gives little control to how these pagination links are generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#pagination a').attr('href', function() {
  return this.href + '?some=blah';
});
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/AmLxs/1).

**Edited** as per `elusive`'s input in the comments.

Comment: @cambraca: You could make this even better by replacing `$(this).attr('href')` by `this.href`, as it is faster and works cross-browser (yes, the DOM _can_ be your friend). `$()` is expensive. And: It wouldn't hurt to fix the formatting of your code snippet.

Comment: +1 for avoided gratuitous use of jQuery when it isn't necessary.

Comment: @elusive: I wasn't sure it was cross-browser. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
$('#pagination li a').each(function() {
    this.href += '?some=blah';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$('#pagination a').each(function () {
    this.href += '?some=blah';
});
```

Change `#pagination a` to whatever selector you need.